# Unable to use Gitlab Ci to deploy two repositories

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab-ci, cypress

I have two repositories in gitLab. One has the frontend app (Ionic, Cypress) and another with the backend (Django, Postgis). To make integrated tests I need both the backend and frontend. When I commit in the frontend I wanted to use gitLab CI to deploy both projects in a server and from there execute a script to run cypress tests. My problem is to deploy two repositories. It works fine with the first, but not the second. I am new to gitlab CI.
My gitlab-ci.yml

```
variables:
  BACKEND: git@gitlab.com:ctavar01/advisor_grammar_es_tests.git

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq
  - apt-get install -qq git
  # Setup SSH deploy keys
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

deploy_staging:
  type: deploy
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: myipaddress
  script:
    - ssh myuser@myipaddress "cd ./app && git checkout master && git pull origin master && exit"
    - ssh myuser@myipaddress "cd ./backend && git checkout master && git pull origin master && exit"
  only:
    - master
```

What I've done in the user account in the target server
Using two key pairs: one for repo backend, the other for the repo app
id_rsa, id_rsa_app
I've added both keys to the user agent in my server
My config

```
# GitLab.com server
Host username1
    HostName gitlab.com
    RSAAuthentication yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Host username2
    HostName gitlab.com
    RSAAuthentication yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_app
```

I've copied both public keys into the corresponding gitlab repos deploy keys
I've copied the private keys into the corresponding gitlab repos variables (SSH_PRIVATE_KEY)

The first script command executes correctly. The second fails in the git pull origin master
I think I'm unable to make the script recognize the second key. What am I missing?

Didn't know how to introduce the requested detail. Posted as accepted answer but it is not. The job output

```
Getting source from Git repository
00:03
$ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/ctavar01/advisor_app/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out f323f983 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:06
$ apt-get update -qq
$ apt-get install -qq git
$ which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )
/usr/bin/ssh-agent
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 267
$ ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
Identity added: /dev/fd/63 (/dev/fd/63)
$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
$ [[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
$ ssh myuser@ myipaddress "cd /home/marketradar_e2e/app && git checkout master && git pull origin master && exit"
Warning: Permanently added 'myipaddress' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
myuser@myipaddress: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: Can we see the result of `ssh myuser@myipaddress "cd ./app && git remote -v"` and `ssh myuser@myipaddress "cd ./backend && git remote -v"` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `~/.ssh/config` file with `Host` entries, then the SSH URL to use would be:

```
myuser@username1
# or
myuser@username2
```

Only by using the `Host` entries would you reference the right private key.

Since the first entry uses the *default* `~/.ssh/id_rsa` private key, it works with the default SSH URL.
But the second one will only work if you use the proper SSH URL, based on the second `Host` entry.